# Script for batch image convertion not working when space in filename

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I try to run a script for converting images to the webp format.
Everything is fine, but my script is not working when a file (or whole folder) have spaces in the name.

I use Imagemagik (Ubuntu 16.04) to convert images to a webp copy in the same location (and keep the same filename). It's important to keep the same file name, file location and use recursive exploration to compress every files.

For example, when running the script:

images/cmsA/fileA.png is  copied and converted into images/cmsA/fileA.webp

but

images/cmsB/file A.png

or

images/cms B/fileA.png

are not converted.

I know something is wrong with my arguments (or missing " somewhere, I've tried to put them but I think I did it wrong)

Does anyone has a solution?

Here's my script:

Thanks :)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Convert all images to WebP
IMAGE_PATHS="img/ motor/ motor2/ modules/"
for SRC in $(find $IMAGE_PATHS -name "*.png" -o -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.jpeg" -o -name "*.gif"); do
    WEBP="${SRC%.*}.webp"
    if [ "$SRC" -nt "$WEBP" ]; then
        echo "Converting to $WEBP"
        convert "$SRC" -define webp:alpha-compression=1 -define webp:auto-filter=true -define webp:alpha-quality=90 -quality 95 "$WEBP"

    fi
done
```

Edit: Solution for my problem thanks to @alecxs

```
#!/bin/bash
# Convert all images to WebP

IMAGE_PATHS="img/ modules/"


find $IMAGE_PATHS -type f \( -iname "*.png" -o -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg" -o -iname "*.gif" \) -print0 | sort -z | while read -r -d $'\0' SRC;



do
    WEBP="${SRC%.*}.webp"
    if [ "$SRC" -nt "$WEBP" ]; then
        echo "Converting to $WEBP"
        convert "$SRC" -define webp:alpha-compression=1 -define webp:auto-filter=true -define webp:alpha-quality=90 -quality 95 "$WEBP"

    fi
done
```

Comment: See [BashFAQ #20: How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to capture all file names no matter what chars they contain you can use the NUL char as separator for built-in read combined with while loop (and sort if required).
please note that file names are case sensitive, <s>you should convert strings to lower case with string manipulation before compare.</s> to capture all files use find -iname.

```
find $IMAGE_PATHS -type f \( -iname "*.png" -o -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg" -o -iname *.gif" \) -print0 | sort -z | while read -r -d $'\0' SRC
  do
    ...
    # if [ "${SRC,,}" != "${WEBP,,}" ]
    if [ "$SRC" -nt "$WEBP" ]
    ...
done
```

Comment: sorry i did not realize what -nt is for [ FILE1 -nt FILE2 ]True if FILE1 has been changed more recently than FILE2, or if FILE1 exists and FILE2 does not

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, everything is working like a charm!